# list of references instead of copies

Tags: python, object, reference

i have several object 'attributes' like :

```
self.blah = Blah()
self.h = {'abc':ABC(), .. }
self.k = {'cde':CDE(), .. }
```

if I collect them in a list :

```
self.refs = [ self.blah ]
self.refs.extend(self.h.values()) 
self.refs.extend(self.k.values())
```

the refs list will contain REFERENCES to the original objects not a COPY of the objects, right ?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: Is there a particular problem you are not able to solve?

Comment: easier to traverse the objects .. they all have common Base.. but i also need the other way to reference them

Comment: What did you find out when you tested it?

Comment: In general, Python never makes copies unless you tell it to, e.g. by using `deepcopy()`

Comment: dont know how to test it .. is there a function to check if var is ref or not?

Comment: You can compare references with ```id(var1) == id(var2)```.